# Why is AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement devouring my CPU?

Tags: macos, macbook, power-management, cpu-usage

Once in a while, for not apparent reason my Macbook Pro (OS X 10.7.5, late 2011 model) will ramp up to 65%+ CPU usage by "System", and stay there for upwards of an hour. If left long enough, the system load will eventually return to normal. The issue becomes so bad that response to keystrokes is delayed, and my mouse and music skip.

htop shows this happening across all 8 cores. There are no apps with exceptional CPU usage, high RAM usage, or disk activity.

While I have no way to replicate this, I've seen this happen immediately after a reboot, with no apps running.

I traced a sample of the system's operations using Instruments and got the following results. Why might AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement devour my CPU?

[image: Instruments trace - AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement 54%]

Comment: On a side note, what process list tool is that? Looks different from the stock one.

Comment: That's Instruments, which can do system-wide tracing of function calls inside processes. It's probably using [dtrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dtrace) under the hood. You can access Instruments by firing up XCode, then going to the menu bar, XCode -> Open Developer Tool -> Instruments. When I used the normal Activity Monitor, no processes came to the top of the CPU list because it doesn't show kernel stuff.

Comment: Resurrecting this, as I've recently discovered the same phenomena in el capitan running on a macbook6,1 (white macbook mid-2009 c2d2.0).  Used dtrace with SIP disabled to track kernel_task and found that with AC power disconnected this same kext kicked in action, consuming CPU with two functions MASTER_CPU_FORCED_IDLE and SLAVE_CPU_FORCED_IDLE. If I remove that kext, kernel_task sits at <10% utilization whether on AC or battery power.